# GUI not starting on 19.10 with Radeon RX 5700

Tags: amdgpu

I have built a new system based on a Ryzen 3700X CPU. I initially installed Ubuntu 19.10 (fresh, on an NVMe drive) with the old GPU installed (a GeForce 250 GTS). Everything worked fine. A few days later, my new GPU arrived and I swapped them over. Now the system boots to a solid purple screen, then a black screen with a flashing cursor, and a `tty` available on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Could I have confused something by switching GPUs?

I am aware that 19.10 does not come with the navi firmware files on the installation media, but fortunately I was able to upgrade `linux-firmware` to 1.183.1 which now has the correct files.

The only errors I can find in logs are the following in `/var/log/Xorg.0.conf`:

```
AMDGPU(0): eglGetDisplay() failed
AMDGPU(0): glamor detected, failed to initialize EGL
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, this isn’t exactly an answer, but I reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch, upgraded linux-firmware, rebooted, and all was well. So I guess the answer was yes, switching GPUs did break something.